# Using Camera high quality image invokes prior Heavy activity destroyed(Android)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera, unity-game-engine, samsung-mobile

I'm now developing Unity app, and want to use camera.

I consider it a memory issue, and I want to know how to limit camera capture image size before getting image in `onActivityResult` invoked.

(for who doesn't know about unity activity, just consider it as 'heavy activity with GL, etc..' and come up with any idea. any help will be appreciated. Unity is in fact a Game Engine.)

activity flow is like this
`UnityTestActivity(Extends UnityActivity) > GetBitmapFromAndroidActivity(extends Activity)`
and I call camera capture intent from 'GetBitmapFromAndroidActivity' activity.

Here's situation that is not related to Unity(Heavy) Activity:

When I use Samsung camera with lower size(ie.640 x 800) `onActivityResult` is invoked after `onStop`, and everything works fine.
When I use Samsung camera with maximum size(3264*2448) , after `onStop`, the prior one(UnityTestActivity) is re-created and `onCreate` is invoked. 'GetBitmapFromAndroidActivity' activity is also being recreated, then `onactivityresult` is invoked. It's weird.

And here are my questions:

1. is it normal android memory-short situation or unity one?
2. and is there any idea that can limit size of camera capture image size before reaching `onActivityResult`? I did `MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT` but had no effect at all.. is it video one?
3. Any Samsung camera well-known memory short issue??
4. Is there any site that I can view "UnityAndroidActivity' source code or similar one?

I'm developing SamsungGalaxyNote and maximum image size is 3264x2448.
I know well-known Samsung camera nullpointer case [Link](http://kevinpotgieter.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/null-intent-passed-back-on-samsung-galaxy-tab/) and it is not the case because mine never calls `onActivityResult`.

Thanx for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Self Reply. I implemented custom camera myself. it never solved. high quality camera capture from unity-like heavy activity never succeded..